flutter fatal: early EOF invalid index-pack output
flutter error
I faced a problem a month ago and I could not solve it. The problem, in short, is that when adding cloud_firestore, the application does not work, and every time I restart the application, this message appears as shown in the picture.
enter image description here


    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A cloud_firestore
      - Flutter
      - firebase_core



Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         
         error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
         error: 255 bytes of body are still expected
         fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.



Hi Khaled! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If anyone encounters the same problem as me, follow the same steps I did in order, and the problem will be solved immediately
I faced the problem for more than a month and it was not solved except with these commands

git init boringssl
cd boringssl
git remote add origin https://github.com/google/boringssl.git
git fetch --depth 1 origin master
git pull origin master

sudo gem update xcodeproj
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install


